# Let $S$ and $T$ be sets such that $|S|=|T|$, prove that $|P(S)|=|P(T)|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

Let $S$ and $T$ be sets such that $|S|=|T|$, prove that $|P(S)|=|P(T)|$ where $P$ denotes a power set.

From the theorem: If $S$ is a finite set with $n$ elements, then the cardinality of $P(S)=2^n$ we can show that $|P(S)|=|P(T)|$ when $S$ and $T$ are finite. I'm not sure where to begin if $S$ and $T$ are infinite sets?

Comment: Try explicitly constructing a bijection, knowing that there is a bijection between $S$ and $T$.

Comment: Is this when you construct a function $f: T \rightarrow S$ and show it is one-to-one and onto?

Comment: In this case, a function $f : P(S) \to P(T)$ that is one-to-one and onto. This will show that $|P(S)| = |P(T)|$. I recommend trying to solve this problem before peeking at posted answers. It's a good exercise.

Comment: So then to show that $f$ is one-to-one, i assume that $f(a)=f(b)$ where $a \in P(S)$ and $b \in P(T)$ and then i prove that this means $a=b$?

Comment: How do i go about making such a function?

Comment: First try it in the finite case, say between $P(\{1,2,3,4,5\})$ and $P(\{a,b,c,d,e\})$, where your bijection between the sets sends 1 to $a$, 2 to $b$, etc. Let's say I pick $\{2,4,5\}$ in the power set. What should it correspond to in the a,b,c,d,e case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to proof card p(a) = card p(b)?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608505/how-to-proof-card-pa-card-pb)

Comment: So then {2, 4, 5} would correspond to {b, d, e}

Answer (score 5):

Since $|S|=|T|$, there exists a bijection $f:S \to T$. We can use this to construct a bijection $F:P(S) \to P(T)$.

Define $F(X)$ as follows, $F(X)=\{t \in T| t=f(s) \text{ for some } s \in X\}$.

This is clearly a function from $P(S)$ to $P(T)$, It remains to show that it is injective and surjective.

**Surjective**

Consider any set $Y \subseteq T$. For every element $y \in Y$, there is an element $s \in S$ such that $f(s)=y$ since $f$ is a bijection, so $F(f^{-1}(Y))=Y$.

**Injective**

Suppose there were two sets $X,Y \subseteq T$, $X \not=Y$ and $F(X)=F(Y)$. Consider an $s$ that is in one of these sets and not the other (WLOG $X$). Then there must be another element $s'$ in $Y$ such that $f(s)=f(s')$, since otherwise $f(s)$ would not be in $F(Y)$. But, $f$ was a bijection, so this cannot be the case.

Comment: So with this answer, do we still need to make an actual function or is this enough?

Comment: There is an actual function (?): $\;F\;$ .

Comment: The object $F$ is a function. It takes every set $X \subset S$ and maps it to exactly one set $Y \subset T$. Specifically, it maps $X$ to its image under $f$, the bijection between the two spaces. So, using the example from Nitin's comments above, $F(\{2,4,5\})=\{b,d,e\}$. It is hopefully clear that it maps each subset of S to exactly one subset of T.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your injective part a little further? do we have to show that s is actually s'?

Comment: We've assumed that there are two different subsets of $S$, $X$ and $Y$ that map to the same set in $T$. Now, using that, we are trying to conclude something that can't happen. We know that one of these sets has an element not in the other one (this is $s$). Since the function $f$ associates each element with a unique point in $T$, missing that element is a problem, since no corresponding element in the set missing $s$ can map to $f(s)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Let $f : S \to T$ be a bijection, with inverse $g$.

Can you think of any simple way of defining a simple function from $P(S)$ to $P(T)$? Can you do the construction in such a way that doing the same for $g$ gives an inverse?

Answer (score 1):

$\;|S|=|T|\iff\;$ there exists a bijection $\;f:S\to T\;$, so define

$$F:P(S)\to P(T)\;,\;\;F(X):=\{\,f(x)\;:\;x\in X\,\}\;,\;\;X\in P(S)$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that when $S$ and $T$ are finite, the bijection between $P(S)$ and $P(T)$ can be constructed by picking any particular bijective reordering in the corresponding subset lattices.

When they are infinite you need to use the Axiom of Choice (if you want to construct an explicit $f$), because it is not at all clear what to assign $p(x)\in P(S)$ to, in $P(T)$.